Falstad simulator AC vs DC voltage problem
I have a transistor amplifier circuit, which can be found in the included image, as well as a save file text. The problem is, if I apply a 1V AC voltage to the transistor base (of course, with a diode to prevent reverse-biasing), then I get less current at the "Hangszóró" resistor, than if I were to use 1V DC.
I don't think this is supposed to happen.

t 368 256 400 256 0 1 -5.052501719367289 -0.05250171940738867 200 default
R 400 240 400 160 0 0 40 5 0 0 0.5
370 304 256 368 256 1 0 0
370 400 272 400 304 1 0 0
r 240 256 304 256 0 910
r 400 304 400 352 0 8
g 400 384 400 400 0 0
x 409 321 451 324 4 8 Hangszóró
x 259 330 324 333 4 8 Line-in\sbemenet
x 407 247 434 250 4 8 β\q200
370 400 352 400 384 1 0 2
v 240 368 240 288 0 1 2 1 0 0 0.5
g 240 368 256 368 0 0
d 240 288 240 256 2 default```


Oh I think it is because of the opening voltage of the diode. I solved the issue by connecting a resistor parallel to the diode.
